# Как обновить локальную ветку Git

Tags: git

По не опыту сделал git reset на локальной ветке master, теперь не получается запушить новый commit. Как можно исправить ситуацию и вернуться на последний commit?
git pull (remote) (branch) делает не то (ну или я делаю не так).

Doit/master - это тот commit, куда необходимо "вернуться" master'ом
[image: Doit/master - это тот commit, куда необходимо "вернуться"]

Comment: git checkout master &&
git reset --hard origin/master

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вначале переключим на нужную ветку

```
git checkout master
```

и теперь по жёсткому перепишем ее на нужную с "удаленной ветки"

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Ну теперь остался дефис и уж букву ё добавить в "удалённой". :)